# How can anyone hold that Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim is d’Rabbanan?

Tags: tzaar-baalei-chayyim, bava-metzia

The Gemara (Bava Metzi’a 32b-33a) discusses the prohibition of tza’ar ba’alei chaim, causing pain to animals, and whether it is from the Torah (d’Oraisa) or from the Rabbis (d’Rabbanan), concluding that it is a dispute amongst the Tannaim - most notably, R’ Yosi HaGlili holds of the latter view. In that discussion, the foremost source for the view that it’s d’Oraisa is the obligation to unload one’s animal (Shemos 23:5), while R’ Yose HaGlili disagrees with that proof on grounds that we’re concerned with the owner’s loss, not the animal’s pain. The succeeding Gemara addresses various sources, but they all have to do with unloading animals.

[Other commentaries bring other sources for tza’ar ba’alei chaim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84532/9682), including:

- Bilam being rebuked for hitting his donkey (Bamidbar 22:32 - Moreh Nevuchim 3:17)
- Not muzzling an oz (Devarim 25:4 - Shitah Mekubetzes, Bava Metzi’a Ibid.)
- Just as HaShem is merciful to all creatures (Tehillim 145:9), so should we (follow in His ways, Devarim 28:9 - Chasam Sofer to Bava Metzi’a Ibid.)

We then have three different sources for the prohibition against tza’ar ba’alei chaim. How, then, can R’ Yosi HaGlili possibly hold that it’s not from the Torah? How does he respond to these sources?

---

<sup>It is noteworthy that the Sefer HaChinuch (550) uses Tza’ar Ba’alei Chaim as a reason behind the prohibition against plowing with two different animals. However, I did not include that in the question as he begins by quoting the Rambam’s reasoning, that one who plows with them together may come to crossbreed them, itself a prohibition. Presumably R’ Yosi HaGlili would explain similarly.</sup>

Comment: Related, and indeed where I discovered some of these sources: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84532/9682

Comment: (1) Regarding Bil'am hitting his donkey: It could be argued that the rebuke was for him hitting _his own_ donkey, which he should have realized would not disobey him without good reason, as opposed to him hitting some other donkey, which he could be forgiven for expecting to be obstinate for no good reason.  (2) Regarding  _ve-Halakhta bi-Drakhav_: It could be argued that _mi-De'oraita_ the _Mitzvah_ only obligates being merciful towards humans.

Comment: I'm not sure how D'ORaita halachot work. Isn't the general rule that the Torah has to explicitly state something for it to be D'oraita? There is no explicit statement in the Torah saying "Don't hurt an animal". Is an *asmachta* considered a halacha D'Oraita?

Comment: @DanF See the link I quoted - that could be why Rabbeinu Peretz insisted on using a Halacha l’moshe misinai rather than an actual passuk. Isn’t the definition of an asmachta that it isn’t actually derived from that passuk? In which case, no, that’s not d’Oraisa. (Cont)

Comment: Be that as it may, can you claim that on v’halachta b’derachav? That seems pretty straightforward as being a “real” source. Is it too far-fetched to argue that since “lahashem haaretz umeloah,” we go back to @Tamir’s claim on Bilam’s donkey, that there’s only a concern for one’s own animals?

Comment: Yes, but the question is not whether those places could be sources for _Tza'ar Ba'alei Chayim_ being _mi-De'oraita_ (if it were so, so could offloading an animal be a source), but rather whether R. Yosi ha-Gelili (and those who follow his _Shitah_) would be compelled to accept it as such, based on those sources. (Or, as you put it from the other direction: "How, then, can R’ Yosi HaGlili possibly hold that it’s not from the Torah? How does he respond to these sources?")

Comment: Regarding Bil'am hitting his donkey, I was _not_ saying that any general rule could or should be learned from it, only that it didn't necessarily provide a source for _Tza'ar Ba'alei Chayim_ being _mi-De'oraita_, and _could_ have been an exception to a rule, that he would otherwise be within his right to hit a donkey he was riding that strayed off the road for no apparent reason (had it not been that in this _specific_ case, he should have known better).

Comment: @TamirEvan I understand that. My only point was that perhaps a similar logic could be applied in the v’halachta biderachav case. Just spitballing here.

Comment: What about Devarim 22:6-7, sending the mother bird away so she doesn't see her eggs being taken?  Or for that matter, not boiling a calf in it's mother's milk, presumably after she's seen/known her calf's been slaughtered??

Comment: @Gary I wanted to post Shiluach HaKan, the first source you mention, but all of the sources I could find indicate that the point of the mitzvah has absolutely nothing to do with having mercy on the mother bird so much as imparting on ourselves the principle of Hashgacha Pratis, that Hashem sees and cares about everything (see further, Sefer HaChinuch 545). Con't

Comment: @Gary I assume you refer to the threefold mention of לא תבשל גדי בחלב אמו, not boiling a goat in its mother's milk (Shemos 23:19, 34:26, Devarim 14:21), with the second half of your comment. All that refers to is the prohibition of eating milk with meat. There is, however, a separate prohibition to slaughter a mother and her child on the same day (Vayikra 22:28) that I had completely forgotten about until you brought that up. But once again, the Sefer HaChinuch (294) explains that it is to drive home the point of Hashgacha Pratis.

Comment: Re: Shiluach Hakan - I had heard that argument that it' s not about mercy. It does, perhaps, beg the pasuk *Verachamav al kol ma'asav* to argue, maybe, that Hashem's mercy is already on the animals, why is there a need for a mitzvah to tell us to do likewise. I'm not saying that we should be cruel to them, but just to question why there would be a need for a specific mitzvah?

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that mention. It was a point in your Q! Can you link the Chattam Sofer's point? I'd like to read it. I may have a follow up on it.

Comment: @DanF No link, sorry. I only have the link to the other question that quotes him. I don’t have a kovetz on that part of BM, so I can’t look it up, either. Maybe on HebrewBooks?

Comment: @DonielF - I think(as far as the ol' memory works, that ancient blue book had a lot of good stuff in it!) that the idea that the milk and meat prohibitions are also for prevention of animal cruelty was in the Hertz chumash, as part of the commentary on one of the three times that verse appears.

Comment: @Gary Interesting. The Chinuch gives a very different reason, something along the lines of certain things are supposed to stay separate.